# Gibt es eine Liste über vorschlagene Korrekturen?

Tags: support, editing

Ist es möglich, die vorschlagene Korrekturen für meine Fragen zu sehen? Ich mache viele Fehler, und es gibt keine Mitglieder, die die Korrekturen akzeptieren können.

Translation: Is it possible to see the suggested corrections for my questions? I make several mistakes, and there are currently no users with the privilege to approve edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until some users have accumulated enough reputation, the only ones who can see the suggested edits list are moderators. This group currently coincides with those users who are also employees of Stack Exchange, since there are no community mods yet.

Since I'm the only German-speaking person in that group, I'm keeping a close eye on that list. Everytime you see that RegDwight has edited 5 questions in 60 seconds, you'll know I've been approving a bunch of suggestions again :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

I think the point of this SE is to *ask* and *answer* questions -- as soon as we take active "teaching" duties, we start focusing more on individuals, and perhaps the site suffers for it.

On particular things in the language you find difficult: please ask!  But if a question is asked on topic A auf Deutsch, and you make mistakes which are not related to the question, I don't think they should receive much attention.

Comment: I agree that we should focus on the actual question. Still, if people want to correct mistakes, I don't see a problem with it, and I'd like to approve their edits as soon as possible. There is [another question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/4/editing-orthographic-errors) on how much to clean up.

Comment: @Tim Yup, I agree, the mistakes which are clear and somewhat 'standard errors' (such as incorrect conjugations and so on) should be corrected.  Just not discussed ;).

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my trying to ask this question in German confused things. I've added a translation, because I think that you've misunderstood me.

Comment: @Tim I didn't misunderstand you, I just omitted a word in my answer!  Sorry, sometimes I can be quite obtuse.  After omitting the answer to your actual question, I then went on to answer the obvious follow-up question: since we can not see proposed edits and we can not see detailed reasons behind individual edits, is it OK to discuss them in comments to the edited question?

Comment: I see, thanks .